# Conditional component import in react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fetch, dynamic-import, fetch-mock

I'm using `fetch-mock` to mock the actual component which uses fetch. fetch-mock doesn't support ie11 and would like to import the example component only if the browser is supported. How can i achieve that ?

1. ABCExampleComponent uses `fetch-mock` for mocking `fetch` used in ABCComponent.
2. LoadComponent should render ABCExampleComponent only if the browser is supported.

LoadComponent

```
const isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
if(!isIE11){
  import ABCExampleComponent from './ABCExampleComponent';
}

//or
const ABCExampleComponent = !isIE11 ? import('./ABCExampleComponent') : null;

const LoadComponent = ( ) => {
  <ABCExampleComponent />
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: What version of React are you using? Is v16.6 an option?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I fully understand your question, but try this
`const Abc = condition ? require('ComponentA') : require('componentB')`

Comment: I guess webpacker looks for all imports/require first before i do the conditional check, so this wont work. But thanks for the suggestion